# how can i deployment management system programme (Visual Studio C# and SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I have finished my management System Program, I used Visual Studio (C#) and SQL server
now I need deployment my program in one File.exe
and when user double Click in this file ... my program, SQL Server and my Database Be installed
please anyone Explain That step by step because i'm beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-click on the project you want to deploy, then select "Publish..." from the menu. Follow the steps and you're set.

YOu may also find this information useful:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: when user double Click in this file ... my program, SQL Server and my Database Be installed